# Better understanding why im getting a Key error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

```
iamfinder = boto3.client('iam')
response = iamfinder.list_roles()
print(response["RoleName"])
```

I want to filter Roles by name in a given account and get a list returned.  Currently I can get a response if I exclude "RoleName". Why am I seeing a Key error when running the above?

Comment: Response doesn't have a key named `RoleName`. Have you inspected the data structure that it returns?

Comment: Always check the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_roles). You'll see the response object described there.

Answer (score 4):

It's because response doesn't have `RoleName` key. It should be `{'Roles: [{ ..., 'RoleName': ..., }] }` Can you try this ?

```
import boto3

iamfinder = boto3.client('iam')
response = iamfinder.list_roles()

Role_list = response['Roles']
for key in Role_list:
    print(key['RoleName'])
```

Comment: this helps alot thank you, also I completely understand why it was not outputting properly.